# Pass multiple strings and multiple values as parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have searched numerous forums and sites and have not been able to find a solution. Maybe I am not looking for the correct thing - but any direction and assistance would be appreciated!

I am trying to join two tables: `UserData` and `ServiceStats`. `UserData` consists of the following columns and sample data:

```
Title           Application
------------    -------------
Site Manager    KB1245;KB3256
FTP_Viewer      FTP1536
```

`ServiceStats` consists of the following columns and sample data:

```
ApplicationName    Vendor
---------------    ------------
KB1245             Kronos
KB3256             Kronos2
FTP1536            File Manager
```

When joining the tables I need to get output similar to the following:

```
Site Manager  KB1245   Kronos
Site Manager  KB3256   Kronos2
FTP_Viewer    FTP1536  File Manager
```

My problem is getting the join to read and recognize when there are multiple `ApplicationNames` for a `Title`.

Again - appreciate any assistance and guidance.

Comment: You have delimited data in `UserData.Application` column. **Don't do that!** Delimited data in a field is a common database anti-pattern. Fix the schema so that each value has it's own place in the database, and suddenly this join problem becomes easy.

Comment: I have approached the team about that - but unfortunately I can't change it.  There are several other items that are based off that delimited field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can cut the OP some slack. As developers, we have to deal with less than ideal decision made by other people. What the OP should have searched for is how to split delimited strings, for which there are tons on StackOverflow.

My solution:

```
;WITH
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT  Title,
                REPLACE(Application,' ','') + ';' AS Application
        FROM    UserData
    ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT  Title,
                LEFT(Application,CHARINDEX(';',Application)-1)      AS ApplicationName,
                STUFF(Application,1,CHARINDEX(';',Application),'')  AS RemainingApp
        FROM    cte1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Title,
                LEFT(RemainingApp,CHARINDEX(';',RemainingApp)-1),
                STUFF(RemainingApp,1,CHARINDEX(';',RemainingApp),'')
        FROM    cte2
        WHERE   LEN(RemainingApp) > 0
    )

SELECT  c2.Title,
        c2.ApplicationName,
        s.Vendor
FROM    cte2    c2
INNER JOIN ServiceStats s ON c2.ApplicationName = s.ApplicationName
```

Comment: I had to do a little tweaking to work in my specific instance - but this sure gave me thre right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a Table-Valued Function which allows me to join to it as well. This also makes my code smaller when I have to use it:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter CHAR(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))       
AS       
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @idx INT       
    DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(8000)        
    SELECT @idx = 1       
    IF len(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       
    while @idx!= 0       
    BEGIN       
        SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        IF @idx!=0       
            SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
        ELSE       
            SET @slice = @String       
        IF(len(@slice)>0)  
            INSERT INTO @temptable(Item) VALUES(@slice)       
        SET @String = RIGHT(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        IF len(@String) = 0 break       
    END   
    RETURN       
END
```

Then to use it:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('1;2;3;4;5',';')
```

It works just like a table so you can even join to it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Split('1;2;3;4;5',';') a
INNER JOIN MyTable b ON a.item = b.Field1
```